# Pass Controller Variables into a Model

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I am using a Controller to get Variables from a field in my Plugin.
How and what would be the best way to pass and use them in other `classes` or my main plugin file.

I thought about using `Sessions` or passing them via URL Parameters, but i am not sure if thats the most convenient way.

Thats my controller:

```
use craft\web\Controller;

class SetUserController extends Controller {
    public function actionSubmitUser() {

        $request = \Craft::$app->getRequest();

        $dateTime = $request->getParam('dateTime');
        $user = $request->getRequiredParam('user');

    }
}
```

e.g. in my main plugin file i would like to pass the variable to a function:

```
// check if commerce record for craft user exists
public function checkCommerceRecord($user) {
    return $this->customers->getCustomerByUserId($user);
}
```

**Update:**

I figured that i need to setup a module, however i cant save the variables into the module, getting `Setting unknown property: wewereyoung\wfwplugin\models\WFWPluginModel::userId`

Module:

```
namespace wewereyoung\wfwplugin\models;

use craft\base\Model;
use craft\validators\ArrayValidator;

class WFWPluginModel extends Model {

    public $setUser = [
        'userId',
        'timeDate'
    ];

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [
                [
                    'setUser'
                ],
                ArrayValidator::class
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Updated Controller:

```
namespace wewereyoung\wfwplugin\controllers;

use craft\web\Controller;
use wewereyoung\wfwplugin\models\WFWPluginModel;

class SetUserController extends Controller {
    public function actionSubmitUser() {

        $request = \Craft::$app->getRequest();

        $dateTime = $request->getParam( 'dateTime' );
        $userId   = $request->getParam( 'user' );

        $setUser            = new WFWPluginModel();
        $setUser->userId   = $userId;
        $setUser->dateTime = $dateTime;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply pass the variables to your plugin or module use:

```
MyPlugin::getInstance()->checkCommerceRecord($user, $dateTime);
```

To pass to a service (see the [Creating a Service](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/services.html#creating-a-service) section of the docs) use:

```
MyPlugin::getInstance()->myService->checkCommerceRecord($user, $dateTime);
```

To pass it with your model use:

```
$model = new WFWPluginModel(['setUser' => [$userId, $dateTime]]);

MyPlugin::getInstance()->myService->checkCommerceRecord($model);
```

Comment: Ah ok, that means that i would create a service that saves the post data as variables from my controller and i can then access the variables in e.g. my main plugin class

Comment: You don't have to "save" them per se, you can simply pass them as parameters. I've added an example to my answer for doing it wiith a module.